# Converting HTTP/2 without TLS traffic into HTTP/1.1

Tags: http2

I'd like to have a listener understanding HTTP/2 without TLS ("prior knowledge HTTP/2"). The listener should then translate the received traffic into HTTP/1.1 and forward it to a desired location.

What would be an easy way to achieve this?

HAProxy appears to be a natural first choice, but unfortunately, non-TLS/ALPN listeners [aren't currently supported](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/converting-http-2-h2c-without-tls-to-http-1-1/2176)

As for Apache, [this appears relevant](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_http2.html) and appears to imply it's not possible (not sure, as I have little experience with Apache):

> mod_proxy_http2 supports HTTP/2 only, it does not provide any
>   downgrades to HTTP/1.1. This means that the backend needs to support
>   HTTP/2 because HTTP/1.1 will not be used instead.

If there's a way to do this with  Apache or Nginx, a pointer to a sample configuration file I could start from would be helpful.

This is for penetration testing purposes.

Comment: The ways to do such translation  have nothing  to do with security. And while your ultimate goal is related to security the techniques you ask for are not. That's why I propose to close it as off-topic.